# In TransactSQL, is it possible to create a function that takes a variable number of parameters (optional parameters)?

Tags: t-sql, variables, parameter-passing, optional-parameters

Yes I know I can do this with stored procedures.  I'm wondering if it's possible with functions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Not like in a stored proc - a parameter still needs to be placed in each argument position, but you can specify that it use the default from the declaration:

```
SELECT yourschema.yourudf(x, y, z, DEFAULT, a, b, c, DEFAULT)
```

Comment: Aaaah!  I always wondered why you could specify a default value if you had to specify the parameters!  Now I know! (This also fixes a design thing where I was passing in nulls, which sometimes were the needed values!  Thanks!  voted up and accepted!

Comment: One thing... I don't know if that's pseudo-code or not, but I thought you *always* had to call a function using the owner name (e.g. 'Select dbo.udf(...'  Can you omit that now, or was that again, pseudo-code?

Comment: @MarqueIV: You can't. In T-SQL a UDF should always be called with the owner name prepended to the function's name.